# Create Docker containers programmatically with Node.js and exposing their ports appropriatly

Tags: node.js, docker, ide, containers, port

I am creating a web IDE application where the users can run their code(assuming their code is a website). For every user running the code, their should be created a container containing his code, that should run, and it should expose the ports he is using to the outside world( so he can view the website he created). Is this the right approach(using Docker containers)? And if yes from where do I start? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Running in docker containers seems fairly dangerous, while in theory they are isolated from the host they still share a kernel. You should have a read through https://security.stackexchange.com/a/107853 and https://blog.remoteinterview.io/how-we-used-docker-to-compile-and-run-untrusted-code-2fafbffe2ad5

Comment: What do you suggest? Are there any (cloud based or not) tools to run the code safely?

Comment: Honestly I don't know enough about this to give an answer I would feel comfortable with someone deploying. On that note I did recently attend a talk by AWS where they taught-ed https://firecracker-microvm.github.io/, which is a lightweight way to run virtual machines specifically designed for isolation, speed, and low memory usage.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks!!

Comment: Another great general purpose question ruined by "I don't like your use-case, don't do that, #won'answer"

Comment: If this is an opensource project, the user can look through the source and decide for himself if the software he's running is dangerous or not. Stop scaring people of the things you don't even understand yourself.